# Sparse and variational Gaussian Process lower bound

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, gaussian-process, variational-bayes

I am learning about the [Sparse and Variational Gaussian Process by Titsias](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9VZWIxSGUs). The explanation for Variational Sparse GP starts at around 1 hour 12 min mark. In slide 29 of the lecture, the author stats that the determine a variational lower bound on the marginal likelihood
$$log\, p(y|X) = log \int_{f,u}p(y|f)p(f|u,X,Z)p(u|Z)$$

where $Z$ is the inducing points, $X$ is the training locations, $p(u|Z)$ is the prior over the inducing function and $Z$ is the inducing points.

The next line of the slide shows that
$$log \, p(y|X) \geq \int_{f,u}q(f,u)log \,\frac{p(y|f)p(f|u,X,Z)p(u|Z)}{q(f,u)}$$
I know that the the log can be brought inside the integral due to Jensen's inequality, resulting in the $\geq$ sign. However, I am not sure why the $q(f,u)$ is not within the log function. If i were to multiply the first equation by $\frac{q(f,u)}{q(f,u)}$, this results in no change in the equation. Then applying Jensen's inequality would mean that $q(f,u)$ would be inside the log equation ?

I am not sure how the variational lower bound is derived. Would appreciate any guidance on how it can be derived !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with your initial expression for the log marginal likelihood:

$$\log p(y|X) = \log \int_{f,u} p(y|f) p(f|u,X,Z) p(u|Z)$$

Multiply by $\frac{q(f,u)}{q(f,u)} = 1$:

$$= \log \int \frac{q(f,u)}{q(f,u)}p(y|f) p(f|u,X,Z) p(u|Z)$$

The integral can be seen as an expectation w.r.t. $q(f,u)$:

$$= \log E_{q(f,u)} \left[ \frac{p(y|f) p(f|u,X,Z) p(u|Z)}{q(f,u)} \right]$$

Push the log inside the expectation using Jensen's inequality:

$$\ge E_{q(f,u)} \left[ \log \frac{p(y|f) p(f|u,X,Z) p(u|Z)}{q(f,u)} \right]$$

Writing this expectation as an integral again gives your final expression:

$$= \int_{f,u} q(f,u) \log \frac{p(y|f) p(f|u,X,Z) p(u|Z)}{q(f,u)}$$

Comment: thank you for the derivation. Also, might you know why the log marginal is written as $p(y|X)$ rather than $p(y)$ ? $p(y|X)$ seems like the likelihood function for the GP.